# How to see redraw activity in QML?

Tags: qml

According to a Qt blog post from 2011, there is supposed to be an environment variable `QML_FLASH_MODE` that can be set to `1` to see which areas of a QML application are being repainted.

I have set this variable for a Qt Quick 2 application that I'm writing and there is no visual difference to running the application without this variable.

Is there any other way to see QML redrawing activity? I'm trying to troubleshoot performance issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `QML_FLASH_MODE` was removed in this [commit](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtdeclarative/commit/906d5c5c40183468f9521277c6244a6c46730de6) as part of refactoring to support separate rendering loops per window. Reason why it was removed is not obvious, but anyway its gone now.

If you think `QML_FLASH_MODE` will help you to analyse your scene, you can always get back to Qt 5.1.1 where it still should be present.

On the other hand, to visually analyse scene is not always efficient. I suggest to use qtcreator's profiling. Take a look at property bindings that reevaluated just before painting happens. This should help you to figure which property changes have triggered redraw and could give you some hints on how to optimise your scene.

If you just want to count fps or log when frames being painted, check [QQuickWindow::frameSwapped](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qquickwindow.html#frameSwapped) signal.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that it was removed. Unfortunately the profiler doesn't show me helpful information either and simply says "<bytecode>" for the parts where a lot of time is lost in my application. See my follow-up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22158605/qml-canvas-performance-issue